# How to set MongoCursor timeout in Phalcon properly?

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

I'm not very familiar with Phalcon, so pardon me if this question is really trivial, but I really couldn't find the answer in API docs. I'm using [\Phalcon\Mvc\Collection](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/master/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Collection.html) for database abstraction inside my models:

```
class MyModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection
```

but it is not clearly obvious from the docs how to set cursor timeout for queries. Not so long ago I used to achieve my goal by using static assigment of MongoCursor timeout property:

```
MongoCursor::timeout = 50000;
```

But in latest Mongo driver for PHP this code triggers "deprecated" notice. So my question is how can I set timeout for queries with native \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection methods like findFirst()?

```
$documents = MyModel::findFirst($query); // need to set timeout for this
```

**UPD:** I removed MongoCursor::$timeout completely from my application and now just use socketTimeoutMS option when creating MongoClient instance. So far, so good.

Comment: Did you look here : https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1568/mysql-gone-away-on-model-save-

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the answer there, I could hardly trace any relation of that problem to mine.